# If I use lodash's union to merge objects based on a set of boolean settings, how would one write it elegantly?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I've encountered a programming problem I've never encountered before. I am merging object data based on user defined settings. Does anyone know how to program this without a bunch of (inelegant) nested if/else statements? `_union` takes an array.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

// Real data structure is more complex, but is an array that contains objects like so
let dataset1 = [{ "name": "John" }, { "name": "Paul" }];
let dataset2 = [{ "name": "Laura" }, { "name": "Eline" }];
let dataset3 = [{ "name": "Boris" }, { "name": "Tanya" }];

// These are use configurable settings, real dataset is user defined
let dataSetActive1 = true;
let dataSetActive2 = true;
let dataSetActive3 = false;

// this is the dataset I need in this case of true, true, false - but how to  
// write this elegantly when the truth/false changes?
let dataset = _.union(dataset1, dataset2);
```

Comment: The most trivial way would be to create intermediate arrays like `d1 = dataSetActive1 ? dataset1 : []` and use those.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the structure of the dataset? e.g. Could you make each dataset an object with `data` and `active` properties?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to do that would be:

```js
let dataset1 = [{
  "name": "John"
}, {
  "name": "Paul"
}];
let dataset2 = [{
  "name": "Laura"
}, {
  "name": "Eline"
}];
let dataset3 = [{
  "name": "Boris"
}, {
  "name": "Tanya"
}];

let dataSetActive1 = true;
let dataSetActive2 = true;
let dataSetActive3 = false;


let dataset = _.union(
    dataSetActive1 && dataset1,
    dataSetActive2 && dataset2,
    dataSetActive3 && dataset3
  )
  .filter(Boolean);

console.log(dataset)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

`filter(Boolean)` will filter out all the **falsy** values from the array, which will be when your setting is false.

Comment: don't forget `union` doesn't just concat - [it also enforces uniqueness by value](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#union)

Comment: @chazsolo thanx for pointing it out, but `_.union` works **only** on primitives

Comment: Which is why there's `unionBy`. But a solution using `concat` is definitely not the same thing at all.

Comment: @DaveNewton, why?

Comment: @felixmosh ... Because union-ing and concatenation are different?

Comment: I'm confused, your answer includes lodash? I would love to not have the dependency, one less thing to worry about!

Comment: @Wolfr, it depends if you are need `union` or just concat, if it is just concat, use `array.concat`

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary to return an empty array for each `Active` variable/const which is `false`.

Since the items in your array are objects `_.union()`, which uses the [`SameValueZero`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm ,would never find and remove duplicates. Because if Object A, and Object B are not the same object, they are not equal. Use `_.unionBy()` with the `name` as the iteratee used as the uniqueness criterion.

```js
const dataset1 = [{ "name": "John" }, { "name": "Paul" }];
const dataset2 = [{ "name": "Laura" }, { "name": "Eline" }];
const dataset3 = [{ "name": "Boris" }, { "name": "Tanya" }];

const dataSetActive1 = true;
const dataSetActive2 = true;
const dataSetActive3 = false;

const result = _.unionBy(
  dataSetActive1 ? dataset1 : [],
  dataSetActive2 ? dataset2 : [],
  dataSetActive3 ? dataset3 : [],
  'name'
);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```